# Where should I ask for recommendation? StackOverflow or Programmers@StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'd like to ask question to get recommendations regarding some framework/technology choices. When I typed question in StackOverflow I got warning that question is subjective and is likely to be closed. Should I try programmers@stackexchange instead?

Here is the question I wish to ask to fellow programmer around the world:

> Which Java web framework do you recommend for intranet webapp (not content website)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question as stated will get closed as it fails the following two tests from our [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq):

> What language should I learn next? *(Unless you have a specific requirement and don't know which language meets that requirement.)*
>
> Which technology is better? *(e.g Java/C#, Eclipse/Netbeans, iPhone/Android)*

Partly because the answer is "it depends", partly because it's not constructive.

If you can reword your question and include the **specific** requirements your web application has to meet then it *might* be OK.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did. I narrowed the scope by providing pretty detailed context in the body of my question. I explained the application, the type of users and so on. You can see it here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/54584/which-java-web-framework-do-you-recommend-for-intranet-webapp-not-content-websit